# Android ActionBarActivity Icon + Title

Tags: android

I am usign ActionBarActivity in my Android app...
My navigation is an ActionBar

this is my code:

main.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/phone"
        android:title="Phone"
        android:icon="@drawable/phone"
        myapp:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/computer"
        android:title="Computer"
        android:icon="@drawable/computer"
        myapp:showAsAction="ifRoom"  />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/gamepad"
        android:title="Gamepad"
        android:icon="@drawable/gamepad"
        myapp:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/camera"
        android:title="Camera"
        android:icon="@drawable/camera"
        myapp:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/video"
        android:title="Video"
        android:icon="@drawable/video"
        myapp:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:title="Email"
        android:icon="@drawable/email"
        myapp:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />

</menu>
```

result:
[image]

But I'd like my ActionBar to be like this:

[image]

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'always|withText' will work if there is sufficient room, otherwise it will only place icon.

```
<item android:id="@id/menu_item"
android:title="text"
android:icon="@drawable/drawable_resource_name"
android:showAsAction="always|withText" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem like your. I found that the menu item only show title or icon So I designed my icon (image with text below) and I solved it. Hope it helps.